# TypeORM db schema Users management

Tags: database, database-design, nestjs, typeorm

I start by saying I'm a beginner with TypeORM, but I'm developing a web app (NestJs) just to study this ORM in more depth.
I can't "think" of a valid solution (at the schema level), which allows me to manage users and the data associated with them in this case:

I have three types of users: "agent", "user manager" and "supervisor". The agent must be able to see only his data, the “user manager“ must be able to see his data and the data of the users under him.
In cascade, the supervisor user must be able to see his data, those of the manager and users under him.

**-Practical example:** a user "X" has been assigned tasks, if user "X" has a manager "R", the manager must see his tasks and the tasks of "X". In cascade, if the manager has a supervisor, the supervisor must be able to see his tasks, those of "R" and those of "X." All these "associations" should have a dateStart and dateStart.
I've seen that there is the closure table pattern, but with this, I cannot handle the dateStart and dateStart fields.

Any advice or example?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you will need to make sure your entity files have the correct relationship decorators. Making some assumptions, but:

Supervisor entity/schema:

```
// imports typeorm
import {Entity, Column, OneToMany} from 'typeorm';
import {Manager} from '../../manager/entities/manager.entity';

@Entity()
export class Supervisor{
  // relationship column assuming supervisor has many managers
  @OneToMany(() => Manager, (manager) => manager.supervisor))
  managers: Manager[];
}
```

Now the same with Manager:

```
// imports typeorm
import {Entity, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne} from 'typeorm';
import {Agent} from '../../agent/entities/agent.entity';
import {Supervisor} from '../../supervisor/entities/supervisor.entity';

@Entity()
export class Manager{

  // reverse supervisor relationship
  @ManyToOne(() => Supervisor, (supervisor) => supervisor.managers)
  supervisor: Supervisor;

  // relationship column
  @OneToMany(() => Agent, (agent) => agent.manager))
  agents: Agent[];
}
```

Now on to agents:

```
// imports typeorm
import {Entity, Column, ManyToOne} from 'typeorm';
import {Manager} from '../../manager/entities/manager.entity';

@Entity()
export class Agent{

  // reverse manager relationship
  @ManyToOne(() => Manager, (manager) => manager.agents)
  manager: Manager;
}
```

If you don't have {eager:true} in the entity for the relation options, your query will look not so pretty, from the supervisor perspective, it would be something like:

```
 //import typeorm and other imports needed
import {EntityRepository, Repository} from 'typeorm';
import {Supervisor} from '../../supervisor/entities/supervisor.entity';

@EntityRepository(Supervisor)
export class SupervisorRepository extends Repository<Supervisor>{
  
  async getManagerAndAgents(supervisorId: string){
    let from = new Date().toISOString();
    let to = new Date().toISOString(); //pretend this is different than to

    return await this.createQueryBuilder('supervisor')
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
           'supervisor.managers', // relationship declared in entity
           'manager', // the name of the left join, think of it like 'AS' in sql
        )
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
          'manager.tasks', // relationship in manager entity to tasks
          'task',
          `task.date BETWEEN '${from}' AND '${to}'` // where condition
        )
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
          'manager.agents',
          'agent'
        )
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
          'agent.tasks',
          'agentTasks',
          `agentTasks.date BETWEEN '${from}' AND '${to}'` // or whatever you need (<, >)
        )
        .where('supervisor.id = :id', {id: supervisorId})
        .getOne();
  }

}
```

After writing that - sweet Jesus let there be a better way, I don't mind being wrong. Also, let this code be written correctly.

I've never found a good way to use dates without using the createQueryBuilder.

Comment: Yes could be a solution but in this way we need to create an Entity for every role, anyway thanks for your solution and your time

Comment: If these are just roles, you could have fields for supervisorId and mangerId and query on those fields appropriately. For roles, it really depends on which approach you are taking to implement roles, such as claims or roles tables. I was under the impression those were separate entities. Good luck finding a solution.